# Finding elements from one array within a certain range of elements of a different array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays of unequal lengths:

```
a = numpy.array([108, 637, 1172, 1304, 2260, 2809])
b = numpy.array([109, 634, 2254, 2814])
```

I want to shorten `a` such that the corresponding elements in each array are similar. The criteria for this correspondence is when the element of `b` lies within the range: `element a - 50 < element b < element a + 50`. Hence, the element with value `108` from `a` is a match to the element with value `109` from `b`. The resulting output should be:

```
a_prime = numpy.array([108, 637, 2260, 2809])
b_prime = numpy.array([109, 634, 2254, 2814])
```

I can achieve this using a double `for` loop configuration:

```
a_prime = numpy.zeros(b.shape[0], dtype = int)
b_prime = numpy.copy(b)

for idx, element_b in enumerate(b):
  for element_a in a:
    if (element_a - 50) < element_b < (element_a + 50):
      a_prime[idx] = element_a
```

However, for large array lengths this will be very time consuming. What would be the fast and more pythonic way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to obtain `a_prime`, where the closest values in `a` to a given value in `b` are set to the same index, regardless of the threshold, as you're looking for the closest values after all:

```
a_prime = a[np.abs(np.subtract.outer(b,a)).argmin(1)]
# array([ 108,  637, 2260, 2809])
```

---

Where [`np.substract.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) will give you the difference of each value in `b` with every other value in `a`, and taking its absolute value gives:

```
x = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(b,a))
print(x)
array([[   1,  528, 1063, 1195, 2151, 2700],
       [ 526,    3,  538,  670, 1626, 2175],
       [2146, 1617, 1082,  950,    6,  555],
       [2706, 2177, 1642, 1510,  554,    5]])
```

Now we only need the [`argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) value of each row, and to use it to index `a`:

```
x.argmin(1)
# array([0, 1, 4, 5], dtype=int64)
```